# How to draw a line inside the ball movement in OpenGLES?

Tags: ios, opengl-es

Currently i am working in ball game app using OpenGLES in iphone, Using GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP to draw ball and movement action from left to right, then GL_LINES to draw a line, but the line cannot draw inside the ball movement, how to solve this?

I tried the sample code:

```
#1

- (void)update
{
    self.timeSinceLastSpawn += self.timeSinceLastUpdate;
    self.timeSinceLastSpawn = 0;

    if (self.timeSinceLastSpawn > 2.0)
    {
        [self target]; // Call the Method target
    }

     for (SGGSprite * sprite in self.children) //SGGSprite is a class
     {
          [sprite update:self.timeSinceLastUpdate]; // call the update method in SGGSprite class.
     }
}

#2
- (void)update:(float)dt 
{
    GLKVector2 curMove = GLKVector2MultiplyScalar(self.moveVelocity, dt); 
    self.position = GLKVector2Add(self.position, curMove); 
}

#3
- (void)target
{
    SGGSprite * target = [[SGGSprite alloc] initWithFile:@"Ballimage.png" effect:self.effect];
    [self.children addObject:target]; 

    int minY = target.contentSize.height/2;
    int maxY = 320 - target.contentSize.height/2;
    int rangeY = maxY - minY;
    int actualY = (arc4random() % rangeY) + minY;

    if(actualY <= 100)
    {
        actualY = 215;
    }

    target.position = GLKVector2Make(480 + (target.contentSize.width), actualY);    
    int minVelocity = 480.0/12.0;
    int maxVelocity = 480.0/6.0;
    int rangeVelocity = maxVelocity - minVelocity;
    int actualVelocity = (arc4random() % rangeVelocity) + minVelocity;
    target.moveVelocity = GLKVector2Make(-actualVelocity, 0);
}

#4
- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
        glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);

        for (SGGSprite * sprite in self.children)  // SGGSprite is a class, render method in SGGSprite class
        {
            [sprite render];             
        }
}

#5
- (void)render
{
    self.effect.texture2d0.name = self.textureInfo.name;
    self.effect.texture2d0.enabled = YES;
    self.effect.transform.modelviewMatrix = self.modelMatrix; // Call the method modelMatrix
    [self.effect prepareToDraw];

    long offset = (long)&_quad;
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);

    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(TexturedVertex), (void *) (offset + offsetof(TexturedVertex, geometryVertex)));
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(TexturedVertex), (void *) (offset + offsetof(TexturedVertex, textureVertex)));
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
}

#6
- (GLKMatrix4) modelMatrix
{
    GLKMatrix4 modelMatrix = GLKMatrix4Identity;    
    modelMatrix = GLKMatrix4Translate(modelMatrix, -self.position.x, -self.position.y, 0);
    modelMatrix = GLKMatrix4Translate(modelMatrix, self.contentSize.width, self.contentSize.height+140, 0);
    return modelMatrix; 
}

// To draw a line, when the user tab on a screen.

-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view]; 

    float xPosition = location.x;
    float yPosition = location.y;

        X =  xPosition/50;
        resultX = X - 4.8;

        Y = yPosition/61.538461538461538;
        resultY = Y - 3.2;

        self.effect = [[GLKBaseEffect alloc] init];
        [self.effect prepareToDraw];
        Test1 = YES;

        const GLfloat line[] =
        {
            0.0f, 0.5f,
            resultX, resultY,
        };

        // Create buffer object array
        GLuint bufferObjectNameArray;

        // Have OpenGL generate a buffer name and store the buffer object array 
        glGenBuffers(1, &bufferObjectNameArray);

        // Bind the buffer object array to the GL_ARRAY_BUFFER target buffer  
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferObjectNameArray);

        // Send the line data over to the target buffer
        glBufferData(
                     GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,   // the target buffer 
                     sizeof(line),      // the number of bytes to put into the buffer
                     line,              // a pointer to the data being copied 
                     GL_STATIC_DRAW);   // the usage pattern of the data 

        // Enable vertex data to be fed down the graphics pipeline to be drawn
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);

        // Specify how the GPU looks up the data
        glVertexAttribPointer(
                              GLKVertexAttribPosition, // the currently bound buffer holds the data 
                              2,                       // number of coordinates per vertex 
                              GL_FLOAT,                // the data type of each component 
                              GL_FALSE,                // can the data be scaled 
                              2*4,                    // how many bytes per vertex (2 floats per vertex)
                              NULL);         
        glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 2);
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Where are you trying to draw this line? Could you post an image of what you are trying to do and what you are actually seeing?

Comment: Here i have edit, please review it and help me