# How to draw a line inside the fish movement (OpenGLES in iPhone)?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

Am working in a simple iPhone game application using OpenGLES framework. `I facing an "EXC Bad Access" error while draw a line on the images`. Here i will explain you what i did and what i tried in my project.

Step:1 I draw a `Background Image used GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`. Here is my sample code,

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        self.context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2]; 

        Test = NO;
        Test1 = NO;

        if (!self.context)
        {
            NSLog(@"Failed to create ES context");
        }

        GLKView *view = (GLKView *)self.view;
        view.context = self.context;
        [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];

        self.effect = [[GLKBaseEffect alloc] init];

        GLKMatrix4 projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho(0, 480, 0, 320, -1024, 1024);

        self.effect.transform.projectionMatrix = projectionMatrix;
        self.player = [[SGGSprite alloc] initWithFile:@"bg.png" effect:self.effect];    
        self.player.position = GLKVector2Make(self.player.contentSize.width, 460); 
        self.children = [NSMutableArray array];
        [self.children addObject:self.player];    
    }

    - (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect 
    {
    //  glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    //  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);

    // Condition satisfied to draw a line code given below, otherwise the background and fish image draw in else part.
        if(Test1 == YES)
        {
            GLKView *view = (GLKView *)self.view;
            view.context = self.context;
            view.drawableDepthFormat = GLKViewDrawableDepthFormat24;

            self.effect = [[GLKBaseEffect alloc] init];
            [self.effect  prepareToDraw];

            const GLfloat line[] = 
            {
                0.0f, 0.5f,
               -3.0f,-1.0f,
            };

            GLuint bufferObjectNameArray;
            glGenBuffers(1, &bufferObjectNameArray);
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferObjectNameArray);
            glBufferData(
                        GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,   // the target buffer 
                        sizeof(line),      // the number of bytes to put into the buffer
                        line,              // a pointer to the data being copied 
                        GL_STATIC_DRAW);   // the usage pattern of the data 

            glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
            glVertexAttribPointer(
                                  GLKVertexAttribPosition, 
                                  2,                       // number of coordinates per vertex 
                                  GL_FLOAT,                // the data type of each component 
                                  GL_FALSE,                // can the data be scaled 
                                  2*4,                    
                                  NULL);                 
            glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 2);
        }
        else
        {
            //SGGSprite is another class and self.children is mutable array.
            for (SGGSprite * sprite in self.children)
            {
                [sprite render]; 
            }
        }
    }

    //render method in SGGSprite class to draw a fish and background image
    - (void)render
    {
        self.effect.texture2d0.name = self.textureInfo.name;
        self.effect.texture2d0.enabled = YES;
        self.effect.transform.modelviewMatrix = self.modelMatrix;

        [self.effect prepareToDraw];

        long offset = (long)&_quad; 
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);
        NSLog(@"TexturedVertex:%ld",offset);

        glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(TexturedVertex), (void *) (offset + offsetof(TexturedVertex, geometryVertex)));
        glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(TexturedVertex), (void *) (offset + offsetof(TexturedVertex, textureVertex)));
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);    
    }
```

Step:2 After i draw a background image for my view am going to `draw a fish images in the screen by using GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`. The fish images are always in moving. Here is my sample code,

- (void)update
  {
      if(Test == NO)
      {
          self.timeSinceLastSpawn += self.timeSinceLastUpdate;
          if (self.timeSinceLastSpawn > 2.0)
          {
              self.timeSinceLastSpawn = 0;
              [self target]; // add fish image
          }

  ```
      for (SGGSprite * sprite in self.children)
      {
          [sprite update:self.timeSinceLastUpdate];
      }
  }
  ```

  }

  - (void)target
    {
    SGGSprite * target = [[SGGSprite alloc] initWithFile:@"img2.png" effect:self.effect];
    [self.children addObject:target]; // Add fish image in NSMutable array

    int minY = target.contentSize.height/2;
    int maxY = 320 - target.contentSize.height/2;
    int rangeY = maxY - minY;
    int actualY = (arc4random() % rangeY) + minY;

    if(actualY <= 100)
    {
        actualY = 215;
    }

    target.position = GLKVector2Make(480 + (target.contentSize.width), actualY);
    int minVelocity = 480.0/12.0;
    int maxVelocity = 480.0/6.0;
    int rangeVelocity = maxVelocity - minVelocity;
    int actualVelocity = (arc4random() % rangeVelocity) + minVelocity;
    target.moveVelocity = GLKVector2Make(-actualVelocity, 0);
    }
  - (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect 
    {
    //  glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    //  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);

  // Condition satisfied to draw a line code given below, otherwise the background and fish image draw in else part.
      if(Test1 == YES)
      {
          GLKView *view = (GLKView *)self.view;
          view.context = self.context;
          view.drawableDepthFormat = GLKViewDrawableDepthFormat24;

  ```
      self.effect = [[GLKBaseEffect alloc] init];
      [self.effect  prepareToDraw];

      const GLfloat line[] = 
      {
          0.0f, 0.5f,
         -3.0f,-1.0f,
      };

      GLuint bufferObjectNameArray;
      glGenBuffers(1, &bufferObjectNameArray);
      glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferObjectNameArray);
      glBufferData(
                  GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,   // the target buffer 
                  sizeof(line),      // the number of bytes to put into the buffer
                  line,              // a pointer to the data being copied 
                  GL_STATIC_DRAW);   // the usage pattern of the data 

      glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
      glVertexAttribPointer(
                            GLKVertexAttribPosition, 
                            2,                       // number of coordinates per vertex 
                            GL_FLOAT,                // the data type of each component 
                            GL_FALSE,                // can the data be scaled 
                            2*4,                    
                            NULL);                 
      glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 2);
  }
  else
  {
      //SGGSprite is another class and self.children is mutable array.
      for (SGGSprite * sprite in self.children)
      {
          [sprite render]; 
      }
  }
  ```

  }

Step:3 Now i draw a Background Image and fish images in my screen. It works perfect. Now am going `to draw a white line (using GL_LINE)` in the screen above the fish images and background image. When i draw a line by using below code,

-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        Test = YES;
        Test1 = YES;
    }

```
- (void)update
{
    if(Test == NO)
    {
        self.timeSinceLastSpawn += self.timeSinceLastUpdate;
        NSLog(@"timeSinceLastUpdate:%f",self.timeSinceLastUpdate);
        if (self.timeSinceLastSpawn > 2.0)
        {
            self.timeSinceLastSpawn = 0;
            [self target];
        }

        NSLog(@"Children count:%d",[self.children count]);
        for (SGGSprite * sprite in self.children)
        {
            [sprite update:self.timeSinceLastUpdate];
        }
    }
}


- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
//  glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
//  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);

// Condition satisfied to draw a line code given below, otherwise the background and fish image draw in else part.
    if(Test1 == YES)
    {
        GLKView *view = (GLKView *)self.view;
        view.context = self.context;
        view.drawableDepthFormat = GLKViewDrawableDepthFormat24;

        self.effect = [[GLKBaseEffect alloc] init];
        [self.effect  prepareToDraw];

        const GLfloat line[] = 
        {
            0.0f, 0.5f,
           -3.0f,-1.0f,
        };

        GLuint bufferObjectNameArray;
        glGenBuffers(1, &bufferObjectNameArray);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferObjectNameArray);
        glBufferData(
                    GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,   // the target buffer 
                    sizeof(line),      // the number of bytes to put into the buffer
                    line,              // a pointer to the data being copied 
                    GL_STATIC_DRAW);   // the usage pattern of the data 

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
        glVertexAttribPointer(
                              GLKVertexAttribPosition, 
                              2,                       // number of coordinates per vertex 
                              GL_FLOAT,                // the data type of each component 
                              GL_FALSE,                // can the data be scaled 
                              2*4,                    
                              NULL);                 
        glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 2);
    }
    else
    {
        //SGGSprite is another class and self.children is mutable array, Draw a fish and background image
        for (SGGSprite * sprite in self.children)
        {
            [sprite render]; 
        }
    }
}
```

The app getting crash in the line "glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4); // ERROR -Bad excess happened here when i touch  the screen"

- (void)render
  {
      self.effect.texture2d0.name = self.textureInfo.name;
      self.effect.texture2d0.enabled = YES;
      self.effect.transform.modelviewMatrix = self.modelMatrix;

  ```
  [self.effect prepareToDraw];

  long offset = (long)&_quad; 
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);
  NSLog(@"TexturedVertex:%ld",offset);

  glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(TexturedVertex), (void *) (offset + offsetof(TexturedVertex, geometryVertex)));
  glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(TexturedVertex), (void *) (offset + offsetof(TexturedVertex, textureVertex)));
  glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);  // ERROR comes from this line, when i touch the screen.
  ```

  }

Can you please refer these code and tell what is wrong with my code? What i should do to fix this problem? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Like with your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10384223/19679 it's really hard to figure out what you're asking here. I have no idea what you mean by "draw a line inside the fish movement". Also, if `Test` is set to YES when you touch the screen, that second `glDrawArrays()` shouldn't be hit, so I don't see how it could be crashing at that point.

Comment: I will edit my question with some more details. Please review it.